# Change my app's icon in xcode (OSX app)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I change icon (drag my icon.png to icon place) but when i run my app, in dock doesn't show icon and show default icon

how can i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should make `.icns` and drag it to your project. you can find information about it from below links:

[Creating icns Icon Files](http://murphymac.com/creating-icns-icon-files/)

[How To: Create Custom Icons for your Mac](http://macapper.com/2007/04/21/how-to-create-custom-icons-for-your-mac/)

[How to Make Mac Icons](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/59)

Answer (score 3):

did u make change in the plist file set "Icon file" field value as icon.png

Then clean and build the project

Comment: where did u drag ur icon ? in the resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean (`Product -> Clean`) your project and build (`Product -> Build`) it again.

Also check that all icon files are listed in `plist` of project.